# Problem in Saving data in excel file in python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to save my result into excel file. I am executing these lines of code but the abc.xlsx is empty. why can anyone help me?

```
data1= data[data.columns[df.isnull().mean() < 0.8]]
data1.to_excel('abc.xlsx')


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openpyxl
data = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/data/mydata.csv')
data.head(3)
data.dtypes

data1= data[data.columns[df.isnull().mean() < 0.8]]
data1.to_excel('abc.xlsx')
```

While executing data1.to_excel('abc.xlsx') this .. the generated excel file is only 0KB why?

Comment: can you print data1 and data1.shape

Comment: yeah.. and and i can see data by all these commands but the saved excel file is 0KB

Comment: What IS the shape of `data1`?  What are you trying to do here, in words?  Is that trying to select those columns where less than 80% of the values are NaN?

Comment: are you working with 2 DataFrame `df` and `data` ?  How about  `data[data.columns[data.isnull().mean() < 0.8]]`

Comment: yeah exactly trying to select where less than 80% of the values are NaN...And second dataframe is after removing less than 80% columns

Comment: I just solved this by saving other dataframe using csv . thanks

Answer (score 0):

from what I can tell is, there is no `Writer` in this script.

```
data1= data[data.columns[df.isnull().mean() < 0.8]]
data1.to_excel('abc.xlsx')


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openpyxl
data = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/data/mydata.csv')
data.head(3)
data.dtypes

data1= data[data.columns[df.isnull().mean() < 0.8]]
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('abc.xlsx')
data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='yourSheetName', index=False, na_rep='NaN')
writer.save()
```

I hope, this helps,

take care.